# constrain a label inside of a UIView which is inside of a expandable collectionViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, anchor, uicollectionviewcell

I have an expandable/collapsible cell in Xcode, and I am trying to do what is said in the title. When I expand the cell, the text is centred inside of the cell and I'm not sure why because I have the label constrained inside of the UIView. I will leave code below,

```
 override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addSubview(SubView)
    SubView.anchors(top: topAnchor, topPad: 0, bottom: nil, bottomPad: 0, left: leftAnchor, leftPad: 0, right: rightAnchor, rightPad: 0, height: 80, width: self.bounds.width - 20)

    SubView.addSubview(textField)
    textField.anchor(top: SubView.topAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: SubView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    textField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: SubView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

}
```

this is how I create the anchors and addSubview.

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "profCell", for: indexPath) as! profCell


    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        cell.textField.text = "Skills & Preferences"


    } else if indexPath.row == 1  {

        cell.textField.text = "Bio"


    } else if indexPath.row == 2  {

        cell.textField.text = "Reviews"

    }

    return cell
}
```

and this is how I try to create the label text. I will leave the two images that show what I am asking.

[image: closed cell]

this is how I want the cell to look even if it is expanded.

[image: expanded image]

when it is expanded, the label moves to the center of the cell.

thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 0):

- You need to understand a bit about **Auto-Layout Constraints**. If you are using `Leading`, `Trailing`, `Top` & `Bottom` constraints, you are not required to add `Center X` & `Center Y` anchors. But even if you add those extraneous constraints you need to be very careful so that they don't conflict with each other. For this purpose, you need to make some of them **Low** priority constraints while leaving some as **High** priority constraints or make them **greater/equal** or **less/equal** instead of explicit **equal**. This is a topic that I can't make completely understandable here in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com).
- Secondly, you have pinned the `leading`, `bottom` & `trailing` constraints to the `contentView` of the `UITableViewCell` itself which is wrong according to your expectation. You either

  1. change it to constraint the `textField` with respect to `SubView`'s anchors here:

     ```
     textField.anchor(top: SubView.topAnchor, leading: SubView.leadingAnchor, 
                      bottom: SubView.bottomAnchor, trailing: SubView.trailingAnchor, 
                      padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
     ```

     and delete those `textField.centerXAnchor` & `textField.centerYAnchor` entirely.

  **Or**

  2. delete the line of setting the `leading`, `trailing`, `top` & `bottom` constraints entirely keeping only the center constraints.

**Note:** Use `camelCased` identifier for properties.